# Trying to find the most efficient way of storing and loading information for a TileMap game engine

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I've been trying to write a Tilemap engine which uses an array of Tile classes to store information. These Tile classes store 8 pieces of information (all numbers), including the texture index and artifact index, but when it comes to saving and loading these arrays it can take a long time, particularly for loading which can take up to several minutes to load arrays of much larger sizes e.g. 100x100. I'm currently using a text file to save information, separating different Tiles with spaces and different pieces of information of those Tiles using commas, and I use StreamReaders and StreamWriters to read these.

```
    public void Load()
    {
        try
        {
            TextReader TR = new StreamReader("C:/Users/Cogythea/Documents/Programming TextFiles/TileMap.tilemap");
            TR.Close();


            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:/Users/Cogythea/Documents/Programming TextFiles/TileMap.tilemap");
            List<string[]> stringLists = new List<string[]>();

            int arrayArea;

            int lineLength = 0;
            int arrayHeight = 0;

            int width;

            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lineLength = line.Length;
                arrayHeight++;

                stringLists.Add(line.Split(' '));
            }

            arrayArea = lineLength * arrayHeight;




            for (int y = 0; y < lineLength; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < arrayHeight; x++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string currentLine = stringLists[x][y].ToString();

                        List<string[]> currentLineSections = new List<string[]>();
                        currentLineSections.Add(currentLine.Split(','));

                        Map[x, y].textureIndex = Convert.ToInt16(currentLineSections[0][0].ToString());
                        Map[x, y].accessoryIndex = Convert.ToInt16(currentLineSections[0][1].ToString());


                        if (currentLineSections[0][2].ToString() == "1")
                            Map[x, y].colliding = true;
                        else
                            Map[x, y].colliding = false;


                        if (currentLineSections[0][3].ToString() == "1")
                            Map[x, y].startLocation = true;
                        else
                            Map[x, y].startLocation = false;


                        if (currentLineSections[0][4].ToString() == "1")
                            Map[x, y].portal = true;
                        else
                            Map[x, y].portal = false;



                        if (currentLineSections[0][5].ToString() == "1")
                            Map[x, y].portalExit = true;
                        else
                            Map[x, y].portalExit = false;


                        Map[x, y].portalNumber = Convert.ToInt16(currentLineSections[0][6].ToString());

                        Map[x, y].portalDestination = new Vector2(Convert.ToInt16(currentLineSections[0][7].ToString()), Convert.ToInt16(currentLineSections[0][8].ToString()));

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }



            reader.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        try
        {
            TextReader TR = new StreamReader("C:/Users/Cogythea/Documents/Programming TextFiles/TileMap.tilemap");
            TR.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            FileStream create = File.Create("C:/Users/Cogythea/Documents/Programming TextFiles/TileMap.tilemap");
            create.Close();
        }


        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:/Users/Cogythea/Documents/Programming TextFiles/TileMap.tilemap");
        for(int x = 0; x < Map.GetLength(0); x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < Map.GetLength(1); y++)
            {
                writer.Write(Map[x, y].textureIndex.ToString() + ",");
                writer.Write(Map[x, y].accessoryIndex.ToString() + ",");

                if(Map[x,y].colliding)
                    writer.Write("1,");
                else
                    writer.Write("0,");

                if (Map[x, y].startLocation)
                    writer.Write("1,");
                else
                    writer.Write("0,");


                if (Map[x, y].portal)
                    writer.Write("1,");
                else
                    writer.Write("0,");


                if (Map[x, y].portalExit)
                    writer.Write("1,");
                else
                    writer.Write("0,");

                writer.Write(Map[x, y].portalNumber.ToString() + ",");

                writer.Write(Map[x, y].portalDestination.X.ToString() + ",");
                writer.Write(Map[x, y].portalDestination.Y.ToString() + ",");

                writer.Write(" ");
            }
            writer.WriteLine();
        }
        writer.Close();
    }
```

I've been looking on the internet for alternative methods to this and I've found that there is overwhelming support for XML files for storing information. Now, I've got 2 questions about this. One, the tutorial I've been using for the code (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203924.aspx) says to use a StorageDevice for the IAsyncResult, but when I declare it Visual Studio brings up one of two problems: if I don't initialise it, it says that it doesn't exist (as you would expect), but when I do initialise it -

```
    StorageDevice device = new StorageDevice();
```

I get the error "The type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage.StorageDevice' has no constructors defined", though it doesn't tell me that there is anything needed in the brackets, so how do I get this to work? Any help with this would be much appreciated. My second question is whether or not there are any other alternatives to this, or even if my original method was correct but needed improvement. I've been trying to solve this problem on/off for 2 weeks in my spare time, so I will really appreciate any help at all. Thanks.

Comment: Several minutes! You have something wrong by at least 3 orders of magnitude, as 8 * 4 * 100 * 100 bytes should read or write in milliseconds at most.

Comment: That's a symptom of a bigger problem, which I'm hoping to find the cause of. An array of 50x20 took about 45-60 seconds to load, and I've got no idea why.

Comment: Try profiling to narrow down the problem code - though it likely has to be in the most deeply nested loop to have that big an effect.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not greatly experienced in programming terms, could you expand on that please? :)

Comment: Some links by searching on "code profiling techniques": (1) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming) and (2): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288073.aspx   Please do callback if you encounter specific problems with this.

Answer (score 0):

For tilemaps, I would never use XML storage. Its too much "control syntax" around something that is basically 2D.

A simple textfile with each row being a row in your map seems more logical or even better, a binary file.

But to keep it easy to read and maintain, you could make a "parser" that will read your XML files, parse them into binary format of your own and then save the binary output as your own tile/map format.

Then you just need a "map/tile loader" that can read this parsed/compressed format of yours.

= both maintaiablity and speed.

its the same with most languages, you write them in "human readable language", then you compile them into "assembler/binary opcodes".